# htaccess cookie value is directory redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a cookie name=dir and value=test. I want htaccess to check if that value exist as a directory and redirect based on that.

```
RewriteCond /var/www/whatever/%{HTTP_COOKIE:dir} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example.com [R]
```

I know it would be possible with a RewriteMap, but I have no access to the conf file and RewriteMaps must be defined there, not in htaccess. A pure mod_rewrite solution would be best, because the module for setenv isn't enabled either. I've tried and googled, but to no avail.

Something like %{HTTP:header} but for cookies would be ideal, but Apache doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to match against %{HTTP_COOKIE} in a seperate RewriteCond

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^dir=(.+)$
RewriteCond /var/www/whatever/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example.com [R]
```

Answer (score 0):

@starkeen: I wasn't aware that i could use %1 in RewriteCond, thought it was for RewriteRule only. Your Answer works perfectly exept for 2 things:

A. Regex. %{HTTP_COOKIE} is a String that can have 3 cases in this Situation:

Case 1: **dir=abc** - Your Regex works

Case 2: **dir=abc; cookie1=v1** - Your Rexex does not work

Case 3: **cookie1=v1; dir=abc; cookie2=v2** - Your Rexex does not work

Also important: it might be something like **dir_save=v1; x_dir=v2; dir=abs**, so something like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*dir=(.*).*$
```

will not work either.

So ... Start with [NEWLINE] or ';[SPACE]' and end with [LINE-END] or ';'

```
RewirteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (^|;\ )dir=(.*)(;|$)
RewriteCond %2 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example.com [R]
```

B. Also check for strange values of the cookie dir, like empty or '\' or '.' or '..\' and so on. On Windows of cause '\' ...

```
RewirteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (^|\ ;)dir=(.*)(;|$)
# must be a directory
RewriteCond %2 -d
# must not be empty
RewriteCond %2 !^$
# must not contain dot
RewriteCond %2 !^.*\..*$
# must not contain /
RewriteCond %2 !^.*/.*$
# must not contain \
RewriteCond %2 !^.*\\.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example.com [R]
```

@all: sorry for answering my own question (also **starkeen showed a vital part** i wasn't aware of) and also sorry for being so rigorous about regex and strange cookie values, but such things can cost you hours to fiddle out in the worst case. I've allready made such mistakes and learned the hard way.